# $\int_{N} e^xy^2 dx \wedge dw \wedge dz + 2y e^x dx \wedge dy \wedge dz + z dz \wedge dy \wedge dz$ over northern hemisphere of 3-sphere

Tags: differential-forms, stokes-theorem

I'm preparing for an upcoming exam and here's a practice problem:

> Let $N = \{(w, x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^4 | w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 | z \geq 0\}$ be the northern hemisphere of the 3-sphere. Calculate:
>
> $$\int_{N} e^xy^2 dx \wedge dw \wedge dz + 2y e^x dx \wedge dy \wedge dz + z dz \wedge dy \wedge dz$$

I'm thinking of using Stokes' theorem for this and then I would just integrate $d\eta$ over the boundary $w^2 + w^2 + y^2 = 1$ where $\eta$ is the expression within the integral. But before that, we notice that $dz = 0$ on this boundary. So would the whole integral just be $0$ or am I missing something?

Comment: First, you need to learn Stokes's Theorem carefully.  $\eta$ is the $3$-form under the integral, so $d\eta$ is a $4$-form. You certainly cannot integrate that over a $2$-manifold.

Comment: Also note that this $d\eta \neq 0$.  Thus $\eta$ is not closed, so cannot be exact.  So we cannot apply Stoke's theorem in the other direction either:  there is no $2$ form $\omega$ with $d\omega = \eta$.  I think your only recourse here is to parameterize $N$ and apply the definition of the integral (pull back to the domain of the parameterization).

Comment: No. There's an obvious and *standard* application of Stokes's Theorem. The hint is: Glue on the bottom disk. (If you haven't seen such things, you might check out a few of my YouTube lectures — linked in my profile — on this stuff.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks much for referring me to your lectures; I watched the ones on Stokes' theorem. Is the idea to integrate $d\eta$ over the volume of the upper half unit ball in 4-dimensions and then subtract the flux through the bottom disc (which is $0$ because $dz = 0$ on the bottom disc)?

Comment: There you go. Perfect.